# Which is the fastest Eigenvalue solver in the Spectra library for a huge sparse symmetric matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvalue, eigen3

I wish to solve the eigenvalues for a large sparse symmetric matrix (typically of the order of 20,000 - 60,000). I have tried leveraging the SymEigsShiftSolver/SymEigsSolver but it takes considerable amount of time to produce my eigenvalues. Is there a way for a speedup?? I have attached a demo code of what I am aiming to do. Am I missing something??

int main()
{

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10000, 10000);
Eigen::MatrixXd M = A.transpose() * A;

// Matrix operation objects
DenseGenMatProd<double> op_largest(M);
DenseSymShiftSolve<double> op_smallest(M);

// Construct solver object, requesting the smallest 10 eigenvalues
SymEigsShiftSolver< double, LARGEST_MAGN, DenseSymShiftSolve<double> >
    eigs_smallest(&op_smallest, 10, 30, 0.0);

eigs_smallest.init();
eigs_smallest.compute();
std::cout << "Smallest 10 Eigenvalues :\n" <<
    eigs_smallest.eigenvalues() << std::endl;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You code example is fusing dense matrices. First thing is to properly assemble a `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>` as detailed [there](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html). Then, on Spectra side, use the respective `SparseSymShiftSolve` helper.

Also, do not forget to compile with compiler optimization ON. This is important for such header-only lib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can obtain eigenvectors and values inside a minute now.

Comment: I produced the changes you recommended, but I am not getting significant speedup. Relaxing the convergence by increasing the maximum iterations or decreasing the tolerance does not seem to help the run time. It almost takes 2 minutes to compute the first 3 or 4 eigenvectors of a matrix as big as 200k x 200k.